How to move focus between wpf images?
enter image description here
Hello, there are several images. One image is in focus and has a red border.
I want the border to move to the next image when the right or left side is selected with the keyboard and to be processed when the Enter keyboard key is pressed.
How to specify borders for all images as a common property and move them
I would like to know if there is a similar method.
PS. this is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do!
Mainwindow.xaml
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,668,310">
    <Image Source="/Resources/1.png" />
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0" Margin="150,0,523,310">
    <Image Source="/Resources/2.png" />
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Margin="284,0,389,310">
        <Image Source="/Resources/3.png" />
</Border>

Mainwindow.cs
private void Image_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            //Image Control Next Move
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            //Image Control Before Move
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            //Running bordered controls
        }
}


You may put the images in a ListBox.

As already suggested, you could use a ListBox to arrange the images. To arrange them horizontally you simply have to modify the default Panel. You probably want to use a WrapPanel if you want to show a kind of gallery where images automatically wrap into the next row.
ImageDataItem.cs
class ImageDataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ImageDataItem(string imagePath)
    => this.ImagePath = imagePath;

  public string ImagePath { get; }
}

MainWindow.xaml.cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<ImageDtaItem> ImageDataItems { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.ImageDataItems = new ObservableCollection<ImageDataItem>
    {
      new ImageDataItem("/Resources/1.png"),
      new ImageDataItem("/Resources/2.png"),
    };

    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Name="Root">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ImageDataItems, Mode=OneTime}">

    <!-- Define the item content here -->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyDataMNodel}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <!-- 
      Add the red highlight border to the item container 
      and toggle it based on the ListBox.IsSelected property. 
    -->
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <Border x:Name="HighlightBorder"
                        BorderThickness="4"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent">
                  <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
              </Border>

              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="HighlightBorder"
                          Property="BorderBrush"
                          Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- 
      Optionally change the default Panel. 
      For example, to change the orientation to horizontal.
      You probably want to use a WrapPanel to horizontally arrange the images.
    -->
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />

        <!-- If you don't want the wrapping use a horizontal StackPanel instead -->
        <!--<VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />-->
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  </ListBox>
</Window>


I guess I asked a strange question... but I added a little more detail. thank you

My answer doesn't change. Have you tried the above code?
